# render from another method

Tags: django, django-views

I have two urls defined in my urls.py one to go to homepage.html and one to go to unauthorized.html. I created the following in my views.py. My goal was to have a common method called "check_authorized" and to call that from my homepage method and if it met a condition here if 'isFoo' is false to call 'unauthorized' method so that it can redirect to the unauthorized.html. However when I call homepage.html it doesn't redirect to that page instead it stays on homepage.html ( I even removed the if block so that the code path hist the 'unauthorized' method directly). Here is the view.py

```
def check_authorized(request):
    ctx = RequestContext(request)
    posixGroups = []
    #Have some logic to add groups

    ctx['isFoo'] = 'foo' in posixGroups
    if not ctx['isFoo']:
        unauthorized(request)
    return ctx

def unauthorized(request):
    ctx = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('unauthorized.html', ctx)

def homepage(request):
    ctx = check_authorized(request)
    return render_to_response('homepage.html', ctx)
```

In my Urls.py I have in the url patterns

```
(r'^unauthorized', views.unauthorized),
(r'', views.homepage),
```

Update:
Adding decorator class

```
def check_authorized(request, login_url=None):
    def is_authorized(u):
        user = request.META['REMOTE_USER']
        posixGroups = []
        #Code to get posix groups
        isFoo  = 'foo' in posixGroups

        if not isFoo:
            return False
        return True
    return user_passes_test(is_authorized, login_url=login_url)

def unauthorized(request):
    ctx = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('unauthorized.html', ctx)

@check_authorized(login_url='unauthorized')
def homepage(request):
    ctx = check_authorized(request)
    return render_to_response('homepage.html', ctx)
```

Error

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
check_authorized() takes at least 1 argument (1 given)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very good use case for a decorator, like [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

It would redirect the user to the `login_url` if it is not authenticated.

So, since you have a custom logic that decides whether to redirect the user to `login_url` or not, you need a custom decorator that would be similar to [Django built-in decorators](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py):

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test

def check_authorized(request, login_url=None):
    def is_authorized(user):
        # Have some logic that returns True/False
        ...
    return user_passes_test(is_authorized, login_url=login_url)


@check_authorized(login_url='unauthorized/')
def homepage(request):
    return render_to_response('homepage.html')
```

Also see:

- [group_required decorator](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1703/)

Comment: I need to read up on this since I haven't used this before but one quick question. Is this another class or do I put the decorators in the same views.py?

Comment: @user3626708 well, if there are multiple decorators, then it would be a good idea to put them in a `decorators.py`, for example, but if it is the only decorator applied to your views, it is pretty much ok to leave it inside `views.py`.

Comment: What does the 'u' indicate in is_authorized? I thought it was just a parameter. I also added a parameter when i called isPasting my code below with the error.

Comment: @user3626708 it is the user, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Realized that I needed to actually change the way user_passes_test works as it does request.user and what we use is request.METHA['REMOTE_USER']. It now works thanks!